# Nodatime Formatting Long Date Pattern From A Specific Culture But Using Month Names From Another Culture

Tags: c#, date, nodatime

In Noda Time, I want to format a Long Date Pattern using a specific culture but using month names and day names from another culture.

My initial code is:

```
var dtfi = (DateTimeFormatInfo) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.Clone(); // fr-FR
dtfi.DayNames = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames; // en-US
dtfi.MonthNames = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;
dtfi.MonthGenitiveNames = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames;
return localDate.ToString("D", dtfi);
```

Cloning DateTimeFormat didn't work. The date was still printed with day names and month names still in French. But if I cloned the CurrentCulture, it would work:

```
var ci = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone(); // fr-FR
ci.DateTimeFormat.DayNames = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames; // en-US
ci.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;
ci.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames;
return localDate.ToString("D", ci);
```

In both code snippets, I traced the code and can see that the day names, month names and month genitive names were assigned before the call to localDate.ToString.

Can anyone explain why the first snippet doesn't work?

p.s. Noda Time is an amazing library and a reason why I still have hair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a problem with the architecture of `IFormatProvider`, basically - which we don't handle as well as we might. Both `DateTimeFormatInfo` and `CultureInfo` implement `IFormatProvider`, but in order to perform formatting in some cases, we need more than a `DateTimeFormatInfo` - we need the `NumberFormatInfo` (for positive and negative signs) and the `CompareInfo` (for text comparisons).

As a result, we basically do the wrong thing when we're given an `IFormatInfo` which isn't a `CultureInfo` - we end up using the current culture.

We have an [issue in github](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/134) for something *similar*, but while it's obvious that if you pass in just a `NumberFormatInfo`, that can't get at date/time settings, it's less obvious that things will go wrong when passing in a `DateTimeFormatInfo`.

I could potentially make such calls throw an exception with a useful message instead of just doing the wrong thing... or I could just use the invariant culture to obtain the `CompareInfo` and `NumberFormatInfo` if you pass in a `DateTimeFormatInfo`.

Note that this may end up being quite slow as we'd have to rebuild the internal `NodaTimeFormatInfo` on each call, as you're passing in a mutable `DateTimeFormatInfo` or `CultureInfo` in each case. It would be better to create a `LocalDatePattern` from a `CultureInfo` - in which case it's up to you not to change the `CultureInfo` any further afterwards. (Basically, `CultureInfo` being mutable is a massive pain.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation @Jon Skeet. If I could vote, I'd vote for throwing an exception for the short term fix so that those like me who are not familiar with the nuances of the framework will know quickly something went wrong. (When using DateTime, both code snippets gave the same output). I also opted to go with creating the LocalDatePattern from CultureInfo. Thanks again for porting and maintaining Noda Time. :)

Comment: @Retard: My pleasure. Will need to consider this issue carefully. It's annoying difficult to get anything clean out of the mess (IMO) of the BCL :(